# Show only time of event in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have an issue when I have several events on a day. I would like to show just the time of the event to the user click, not the title. When there is more than one event it makes difficult to show the calendar in a small size space.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing how you are implementing it. The simple answer would be to loop through the events depending on the view and set the title to an empty string ''.

Comment: I used `$('.fc-event-title').each(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });` but when switch from week to day and back to week the events come back again.

Comment: To set the event titles to an empty string leaves a colored space near event time. So I used remove();

Comment: Is there a way to listen the event of changing calendar view object?

Comment: Should be able to use the eventRender: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Comment: Yes, very true. I used eventRender and things gone fine.